# Calling cmd.exe using PowerShell, spawn multiple instances asynchronously. Don't wait for cmd.exe to close

Tags: powershell, asynchronous, cmd

I am writing a function that will establish remote Wireshark packet capture sessions for VMs living on ESXi hosts.

This function will be given an array of vNIC objects, then based on information for each vNIC, will use plink and Wireshark locally to establish a remote live pcap feed using plink stdout > wireshark stdin.

I have decided to use cmd.exe to call plink/wireshark as the nuances of pipes in calling external commands in powershell have defeated me, happy to be shown another way to do this though.

I need to call the plink/wireshark command like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" -batch -l root -pw PASSWORD -P 22 remotehost.com pktcap-uw --switchport 1112222 -o - |
    "C:\Program Files\Wireshark\wireshark.exe" -o "gui.window_title:VMName - Network adapter X - 1112222 - Portgroupname - VMHost" -k -i -
```

The code to produce the above command looks like this:

```
$command = "`"$($PlinkPath)`" -batch -l $($ESXiRootCredential.Username) -pw $($ESXiRootCredential.GetNetworkCredential().password) -P 22 $($currentHost.Name) pktcap-uw --switchport $($currentvNICSwitchPortInfo.portID) -o - `| `"$($WireSharkPath)`" -o `"gui.window_title:$($currentvNICSwitchPortInfo.VM.Name) - $($currentvNICSwitchPortInfo.Name) - $($currentvNICSwitchPortInfo.PortID) - $($currentvNICSwitchPortInfo.PortgroupName) - $($currentvNICSwitchPortInfo.VMHost.Name)`" -k -i - &"
```

This portion of the script works. The issue is with calling `$command` in `cmd.exe` using powershell but asynchronously so that if I pass in multiple vNICs, the for loop will spawn `cmd.exe` with $command then immediately move onto doing the same for the next vNIC, and so on.

I've tried a combination of several methods:

`Invoke-Command`
`Invoke-Expression`
`& cmd.exe /c`
etc.

```cs
#Requires -Modules VMware.VimAutomation.Common

function New-RemoteVMvNICPacketCapture {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [VMware.VimAutomation.Types.NetworkAdapter[]]$vNIC,

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true )]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$ESXiRootCredential,

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [String]$WireSharkPath = 'C:\Program Files\Wireshark\wireshark.exe',

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [String]$PlinkPath = 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe'
    )

    Begin {
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
        Write-Debug $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name

        # Import function needed to get switch port ID(s)
        try {
            . "$PSScriptRoot\Get-VMvNICSwitchPortInfo.ps1"
        } catch {
            Write-Error "Unable to import function Get-VMvNICSwitchPortInfo, exiting!"
            break
        }
    }

    Process {
        try {
            # Get unique list of ESXi hosts from supplied vNICs(s)
            $uniqueESXiHosts = $vNIC |
                               Sort-Object -Property {$_.Parent.VMHost} |
                               Select-Object @{N="VMHost";E={$_.Parent.VMHost}} -Unique

            foreach ($ESXiHost in $uniqueESXiHosts) {
                # Get VMHost handle from current array index
                $currentHost = $ESXiHost.VMHost

                $sshService = $currentHost |
                              Get-VMHostService |
                              Where-Object {$_.Key -eq 'TSM-SSH'}

                if ($sshService.Running -ne $true) {
                    $sshService | Start-VMHostService
                }

                if (-not (Test-NetConnection -Port 22 -ComputerName $currentHost)) {
                    Write-Error "Unable to connect to \"$currentHost\" on port 22. Skipping the following VMs: " +  + ([String]::Join(', ',($vNIC | Where-Object {$_.Parent.VMHost -eq $currentHost} | Sort-Object -Property Parent).Parent.Name))
                    break
                } else {
                    Write-Host "Able to connect to $currentHost on port 22"
                }

                foreach ($vnic in ($vNIC | Where-Object {$_.Parent.VMHost -eq $currentHost} | Sort-Object -Property Parent)) {
                    $currentvNICSwitchPortInfo = $vnic | Get-VMvNICSwitchPortInfo

                    # Create remote wireshark capture session
                    $command = "`"$($PlinkPath)`" -batch -l $($ESXiRootCredential.Username) -pw $($ESXiRootCredential.GetNetworkCredential().password) -P 22 $($currentHost.Name) pktcap-uw --switchport $($currentvNICSwitchPortInfo.portID) -o - `| `"$($WireSharkPath)`" -o `"gui.window_title:$($currentvNICSwitchPortInfo.VM.Name) - $($currentvNICSwitchPortInfo.Name) - $($currentvNICSwitchPortInfo.PortID) - $($currentvNICSwitchPortInfo.PortgroupName) - $($currentvNICSwitchPortInfo.VMHost.Name)`" -k -i - &"

                    Write-Host $command -ForegroundColor Yellow

                    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& cmd.exe /c "$($command)"}
                }    

                if ($sshService.Running -eq $false) {
                    $sshService | Stop-VMHostService -Confirm:$false
                }
            }
        } catch [Exception] {
            Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
            throw "Unable to establish remote pcap"
        }
    }

    End {}
}
```

This should spawn multiple instances of plink/wireshark one after another without having to wait. At the moment it spawns the first one and then waits for wireshark to close (and the associated cmd.exe process) before continuing.

Comment: `Invoke-Command` is by design synchronous (unless you use it with remoting and `-AsJob`); for asynchronous execution, use `Start-Job` to launch your commands as background job, or , in simpler cases, `Start-Process`. As an aside: there is no need to involve `cmd.exe` when calling an external console application (your `&` at the end of the command line suggests an attempt to launch a background job, but even `cmd.exe` doesn't support that).

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for your reply. Will `Start-Job` or `Start-Process` be able to launch the commands and have the relevant processes come to the foreground? Based on my testing it looked like they were only good for starting background jobs. The expected outcome of each iteration is to spawn a new Wireshark window. The reason I used cmd.exe was because the pipe `|` was being problematic when running the command in Powershell. Not so much a limitation with the shell, more a lack of understanding on my part. The ampersand is so I can have multiple instances of Wireshark open at once.

Comment: `Start-Process` will by default create a window for a console application. I missed that your command line had a `|`, so, yes, you need a shell such as `cmd.exe` for your command. Is the `&` something that WireShark is supposed to interpret? Without quoting, a trailing `&` will be interpreted by `cmd.exe` and simply _ignored_ (given that no command follows it).